# Removing common elements and adding new from one array to another using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays in input,

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var array2 = [3,4,6,8];
```

Output should be:

```
var finalArray = [1,2,5,8];
```

Please suggest me a solution using javascript.
I want to iterate on array1.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Show to us some code

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: First write the logic behind this, then add the attempted solution and why it is not working so that someone can help you. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @sabithpocker: well, it actually is, see below ;(

Comment: @georg No complaints in democracy as every complaint is a responsibility for self :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array.prototype.filter` and array.prototype.concat:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var arr2 = [3,4,6,8];

var res = [].concat(
  arr1.filter(e => !arr2.includes(e)),
  arr2.filter(e => !arr1.includes(e))
);

console.log(res);
```

And even shorter with ES6 `spread`:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var arr2 = [3,4,6,8];

var res = [...arr1.filter(e => !arr2.includes(e)), ...arr2.filter(e => !arr1.includes(e))];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` and `concat`

```
var output = array1.filter( s => !array2.includes(s) ) 
             .concat( 
                array2.filter( s => !array1.includes(s) ) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var array2 = [3, 4, 6, 8];

var output = array1.filter(s => !array2.includes(s)).concat(array2.filter(s => !array1.includes(s)));

console.log(output);
```

**Explanation**

1) First, `filter` out the values from `array1` which are in `array2`

2) Second, `filter` out the values from `array2` which are in `array1`

3) `concat` 1) and 2)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.filter()` to filter your arrays for containing any elements, which are also contained in the other array and then combine them using `.concat()`:

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

var array2 = [3, 4, 6, 8];

var arr1 = array1.filter(e => !array2.find(f => f == e));
var arr2 = array2.filter(e => !array1.find(f => f == e));
var arr = arr1.concat(arr2);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Array's `filter()` and `concat()`:

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var array2 = [3,4,6,8];

var res = array1.filter( i => !array2.includes(i));
var temp = array2.filter( i => !array1.includes(i));
res = res.concat(temp)
console.log(res);
```